# What does the following example code from RxSwift/RxCocoa do?

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I'm trying to understand in detail

```
.drive(resultsTableView.rx_itemsWithCellIdentifier("WikipediaSearchCell",
       cellType: WikipediaSearchCell.self)) 
          { (_, viewModel, cell) in
              cell.viewModel = viewModel
          }
```

from WikipediaSearchViewController.swift lines 47-64.
I've tried to extract the arguments to look at the concrete type signatures, but a rewrite to

```
    let temp1 = searchBar.rx_text
        .asDriver()
        .throttle(0.3)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .flatMapLatest { query in
            API.getSearchResults(query)
                .retry(3)
                .retryOnBecomesReachable([], reachabilityService: ReachabilityService.sharedReachabilityService)
                .startWith([]) // clears results on new search term
                .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: [])
        }
        .map { results in
            results.map(SearchResultViewModel.init)
    }

    let driveArg1 = resultsTableView.rx_itemsWithCellIdentifier("WikipediaSearchCell", cellType: WikipediaSearchCell.self)
    let driveArg2 = { (_, viewModel: SearchResultViewModel, cell: WikipediaSearchCell) in
        cell.viewModel = viewModel
    }
    temp1.drive(driveArg1, curriedArgument: driveArg2)
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

gives

> cannot invoke 'rx_itemsWithCellIdentifier' with an argument list of type '(String, cellType: UITableViewCell.Type)'

for driveArg1 and

> type of expression is ambiguous without more context

for driveArg2.

The signatures of `drive` and `rx_itemsWithCellIdentifier` are

```
public func drive<R1, R2>(with: Self -> R1 -> R2, curriedArgument: R1) -> R2 {}

public func rx_itemsWithCellIdentifier(cellIdentifier: String, cellType: Cell.Type = Cell.self)(source: O)(configureCell: (Int, S.Generator.Element, Cell) -> Void) -> Disposable {}
```

but at this point Swift syntax is darn incomprehensible for me. Can anyone explain the signatures and what happens in the code?

Comment: I'm understood that there is some kind of generic type mismatch. And It can't figured out generic type of the (S: SequenceType) in rx_itemsWithCellIdentifier function parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, Swift compiler cannot infer the type of `driveArg1` and `driveArg2` because of a lack of context. When used inline within the `drive()` call, the compiler have more clues as of what the type of each parameter can be, and we end-up not needing to annotate for those types.

Taking this into account, lets try to add type annotation for those two variables.

First, we'll update the signature of `rx_itemsWithCellIdentifier` with swift 2.2 in mind, removing the confusing currying syntax and also adding the generic annotations

```
public func rx_itemsWithCellIdentifier
  <S: SequenceType, Cell: UITableViewCell, O : ObservableType where O.E == S>
  (cellIdentifier: String, cellType: Cell.Type = Cell.self)
    -> (source: O)
    -> (configureCell: (Int, S.Generator.Element, Cell) -> Void) 
    -> Disposable
```

## Type of `driveArg2`

It's the argument we pass to `curriedArgument` of `drive()`, and will be the argument we pass to `rx_itemsWithCellIdentifier` after applying `(source: O)`. Thus, it needs to match `(Int, S.Generator.Element, Cell) -> Void`

There are two unknown in this type definition, `S.Generator.Element` and `Cell`. They are generic, so we need to figure out what they are.

- `Cell` is easy, it's the type of the cell we want to configure, here `WikipediaSearchCell`.
- `S.Generator.Element` is a bit harder, but we can figure it out pretty easily. We get from `O.E == S` that the type of the sequence is the type we find between the angle bracket of our source element. In our case, source (`temp1`) is of type `Observable<[SearchResultViewModel]>`. So `S`'s type is `[SearchResultViewModel]` hence, `S.Generator.Element` will be `SearchResultViewModel`

Good, we now have the signature of `driverArg2`:

```
(Int, SearchResultViewModel, WikipediaSearchCell) -> Void
```

To simplify what comes next, lets define a `typealias` for it

```
typealias CellConfigurator = (Int, SearchResultViewModel, WikipediaSearchCell) -> Void
```

We can now define `driveArg2`

```
let driveArg2: CellConfigurator = { (_, viewModel: SearchResultViewModel, cell: WikipediaSearchCell) in
    cell.viewModel = viewModel
}
```

## Type of `driveArg1`

Now that `driveArg2` is out of the way, figuring out the type `driveArg1` of gets easier. It is simply the return type of `rx_itemsWithCellIdentifier`, with the generic portion replaced

```
typealias DriveArg2Type = (source: Observable<[SearchResultViewModel]>) -> (CellConfiguration) -> Disposable
```

## `drive` signature

With all this expanded, the type signature for `drive` hopefully makes more sense:

```
drive(Self -> R1 -> R2, curriedArgument: R1) -> R2
// where
Self = Observable<[SearchResultViewModel]>
R1 = CellConfigurator
R2 = Disposable
```